# express.js app.get('/images/1.gif' ... issue

Tags: node.js, express, nowjs-sockets

i have the following code, which is part of an express application i am trying to build:

```
app.get('/stat/1.gif', function( req, res ) {
    var time = +new Date();
    var origin;
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/gif'});
    origin = /\/(.*)\.gif/.exec(req.url);
    console.log(origin);
    if (origin) {
        var ip = req.ip;
        if (ip === null || ip === "127.0.0.1") {
            ip = "82.246.239.187";
        }
        location = geoip.lookup(ip);
        console.log(location);
        var obj;
        console.log(location.city);
        console.log(location.ll[1]);
        console.log(location.ll[0]);
        obj = {
            city: location.city
            ,longitude: location.ll[1]
            ,latitude: location.ll[0]
            ,ip: ip
            ,timestamp: time
        };
        console.log(obj);
    everyone.now.receiveLocation(obj);
    } else {
        console.log( 'fixme no origin' );
    }
});
```

looking at the console.log() i get as the obj

```
{ city: 'Nîmes',
  longitude: 4.3596,
  latitude: 43.8338,
  ip: '82.246.239.187',
  timestamp: 1359930392288 }
```

but i keep getting this error:

```
TypeError: Property 'receiveLocation' of object #<Object> is not a function
    at /Users/khinester/Documents/Tutorials/Node/Blade/server.js:188:18
    at callbacks (/Users/khinester/Documents/Tutorials/Node/Blade/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:161:37)
    at param (/Users/khinester/Documents/Tutorials/Node/Blade/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:135:11)
    at pass (/Users/khinester/Documents/Tutorials/Node/Blade/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:142:5)
    at Router._dispatch (/Users/khinester/Documents/Tutorials/Node/Blade/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:170:5)
    at Object.router (/Users/khinester/Documents/Tutorials/Node/Blade/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:33:10)
    at next (/Users/khinester/Documents/Tutorials/Node/Blade/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:199:15)
    at resume (/Users/khinester/Documents/Tutorials/Node/Blade/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/static.js:60:7)
    at SendStream.error (/Users/khinester/Documents/Tutorials/Node/Blade/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/static.js:73:37)
    at SendStream.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:115:20)
```

I am using the https://github.com/bluesmoon/node-geoip

I was using https://github.com/kuno/GeoIP with the following code:

```
app.get('/stat/1.gif', function( req, res, next ) {
    var time = +new Date();
    var origin;
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/gif'});
    origin = /\/(.*)\.gif/.exec(req.url);
    if (origin) {
        var ip = req.headers['x-real-ip'];
        if (ip === null || ip === "127.0.0.1") {
            ip = "82.246.239.187";
        }
        city.lookup(ip, function(err, location) {
            var obj;
            if ( !err && location ) {
                obj = {
                    city: location.city
                    ,longitude: location.longitude
                    ,latitude: location.latitude
                    ,ip: ip
                    ,timestamp: time
                };
            } else { 
                console.log( 'server fake location' );
                obj ={ 
                    city: 'Bexleyheath',
                    longitude: 0.15000000596046448,
                    latitude: 51.45000076293945,
                    ip: '86.173.61.119',
                    timestamp: 1343054092459 
                };
            }
            everyone.now.receiveLocation(obj);
            console.log(obj);
        });
    console.log(origin[1], req.connection.remoteAddress, req.headers['user-agent']);
    } else {
        console.log( 'fixme no origin' );
    }
});
```

this works fine, but i need to use geoip-lite as the host where i want to hot this does not have the geoip c library.

any advice much appreciated.

Comment: How are you defining `receiveLocation`? That is where the error is coming from, not your geoip logic. It says it is an object, not a function.

Comment: receiveLocatation is in my map.js code https://github.com/TZM/tzm-blade/blob/master/public/js/map.js#L11 but as i said in my original message, when i use goeip i pass the same obj to everyone.now.receiveLocation(obj); and this works!

Comment: Thanks for the extra info. Now that I see that, I can make a guess at least. In map.js, you only assign that value after the jQuery ready callback runs. The main difference between your two code examples is that one is asynchronous, and one is synchronous. Maybe now you try to call `receiveLocation` before the jQuery function creates it client-side, due to timing differences?